# Lead and Lag Function in informatica

Tags: informatica

How can we use Lead and Lag functions in Informatica?

```
Name  |   No.
------------
X     |  100
Y     |  200
Z     |  300
```

I have to convert it to:

```
Name  |    No. |    Lead(No.) 
-----------------------------
X     |   100  |    200
Y     |   200  |    300
Z     |   300  |    100


Name  |    No.  |   Lag(No.)    
----------------------------
X     |   100   |   0
Y     |   200   |   100
Z     |   300   |   200
```

The logic I used was:

EXP Transformation

```
Name (input & Output Port)
No. (input)
O_No.(VAR)=IIF(Prv_no IS NULL,0,No.)
Prv_no.(VAR)=No.
```

This was for Lag Function.

Answer (score 1):

Never done that, but I would use the order of evaluation. In a EXP transformation, input port are evaluated before variable port that in turn are evaluated before output port. Also the row are readed one at a time.

If you send to the EXP TRAN sorted data, you could simulate lag() function. For Lead() you should reverse the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways-

1. You can use *RANK* transformation,check the rank (R) option for No..Set *Top/Bottom* as Top and *Number of Ranks* as 1 for
   getting the *lead value*.**Set *Top/Bottom* as Bottom and *Number
   of Ranks* as 1 for getting the *lag value*. Then using these
   values in expression transformation, we can implement lead/lag
   function.

   2.Use sql query in source qualifier, select *MAX()* and *MIN()* to get the respective lead and lag values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Informatica Expressions to achieve lead and lag. For every incoming row make 2 output ports one for lead and one for lag calculation. Use mapping parameter for configuraing lead and lag variable for the run. After expression connect the ports to two different targets.